# Override default path for model in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my current system, I want to user to be able to navigate to a list using the list name which is unique for each user. I did this using the route resource parameter `param: "name"` But when I'm trying to navigate to the path or link_to, it is still using the id.

Is there anyway of overriding the default..

For example I'm having to do this:

```
profile_list_path(current_user.user_name, list.name)
```

but I want to be able to do this:

```
profile_list_path(current_user, list)
```

Comment: it looks like you want to override to_param: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/to_param

Comment: @hjing Maybe you should post that as an answer and the OP should mark it as answered?